# How to impelement correspond function in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner of Prolog and I'd like to know how to implement this correspond function.

> ```
> correspond(E1, L1, E2, L2)
> ```
>
> this holds when in one place where list `L1` has the value `E1`, `L2`
>   has `E2`. This must work in any mode in which `L1` and `L2` are proper
>   lists (that is, either `[]` or a list whose tail is a proper list).
>   For example:
>
> ```
> correspond(e,[h,e,l,l,o],X,[1,2,3,4,5])
> ```
>
> should have only the solution `X = 2`.

Here is what I have tried by now:

```
 correspond(E1, L1, E2, L2).
 correspond(E1,[Elt1|List1],E2,[Elt2|List2]) :-
     nth0(Index, [Elt1|List1], E1).
     nth0(Index, [Elt2|List2], E2).
```

I wanted to use `Index` as intermediate to get the value of `E1` or `E2`, but these code returns either True or False.

Comment: I tried to run this command derictly in swi-prolog, it seems returns the correct answer. "nth0(Index, [h,e,l,l,o],e), nth0(Index, [1,2,3,4,5], E2). "

Comment: Your third line ends with a dot (`.`), making the 4th a new fact. I think the third line was meant to end with a comma (`,`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I tried, and it works at least for your example :

`correspond(e,[h,e,l,l,o],X,[1,2,3,4,5])` has the solution `X = 2`

Code :

```
correspond(E1,[E1|_T1],E2,[E2|_T2]).
correspond(E1,[_H1|T1],E2,[_H2|T2]) :-
    correspond(E1,T1,E2,T2).
```

Explanation :

- if E1 is the first element of the first list, then E2 should be the first element of the second list.
- else, we try the same with tails of lists 1 and 2 and we iterate recursively.

Note that :

`correspond(l,[h,e,l,l,o],X,[1,2,3,4,5])` has both solutions `X = 3` and `X = 4`.

Try `correspond(X,[h,e,l,l,o],Y,[1,2,3,4,5]` and you'll get :

- `X = h, Y = 1`
- `X = e, Y = 2`
- `X = l, Y = 3`
- `X = l, Y = 4`
- `X = o, Y = 5`
- `false`

---

### Edit:

If you ***really*** want to get `true` instead of `false` after the last result, you might want to prepend the predicate :

```
correspond(_,[],_,[]).
```

Resulting in :

```
correspond(_,[],_,[]).
correspond(E1,[E1|_T1],E2,[E2|_T2]).
correspond(E1,[_H1|T1],E2,[_H2|T2]) :-
    correspond(E1,T1,E2,T2).
```

This means when you try it with empty lists (e.g. the last iteration when lists are of same size), it is `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I try to get  more results, it ends up with a 'false'. Is there any way to avoid that 'false'?

Comment: @YQ-YD Most predicates with multiple solutions do that. It just means there was a choice point left on the trail that Prolog had to investigate, but didn't go anywhere. Usually getting rid of them is more trouble than it's worth. This is one of those cases, because Prolog doesn't realize it's out of list items until it goes back to get you another result.

Comment: @YQ-YD made an edit so it ends up with 'true' instead of 'false' when lists are of same size.

Comment: I prefer the solution without the additional rule. The extra rule says "Anything corresponds to anything if the lists are empty," which doesn't read as true to me, since in the other cases, E1 and E2 correspond to each other because they're at the same location in the list. `_` and `_` are not even present in the lists—the lists are empty. This greatly confuses the intent. Sometimes the right thing to do is not unify.

Comment: @DanielLyons yes but then how do you understand "*This must work in any mode in which L1 and L2 are proper lists (that is, **either `[]`** ...*" ? Anyway, that's just a workaround trying to answer the OP's comment on this answer :)

Comment: It "worked" before. Failing to unify is not the same as throwing an exception. I understand you're trying to make the OP happy, I just think what the OP wants is wrong.

Comment: @DanielLyons that's right, I added one word to my answer to clarify it